# How do i remove a substring from an nsstring?

Tags: iphone, regex, replace, nsstring, substring

Ok, say I have the string "`hello my name is donald`"

Now, I want to remove everything from "`hello`" to "`is`"
The thing is, "`my name`" could be anything, it could also be "`his son`"

So basically, simply doing `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString` won't work.

(I do have RegexLite)

How would I do this?

Comment: If the substring is always the same, you don't need and you shouldn't use regexes for this.

Comment: You're not serious?? I;m just using this string as an example!! return @"donald" helps nobody, and is not the point of this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use like below it will help you

```
NSString *hello = @"his is name is isName";
NSRange rangeSpace = [hello rangeOfString:@" " 
                                  options:NSBackwardsSearch];
NSRange isRange = [hello rangeOfString:@"is" 
                               options:NSBackwardsSearch 
                                 range:NSMakeRange(0, rangeSpace.location)];

NSString *finalResult = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",[hello substringToIndex:[hello rangeOfString:@" "].location],[hello substringFromIndex:isRange.location]];
NSLog(@"finalResult----%@",finalResult);
```

Answer (score 0):

The following NSString Category may help you. It works good for me but not created by me. Thanks for the author.

**NSString+Whitespace.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NSString (Whitespace)

- (NSString *)stringByCompressingWhitespaceTo:(NSString *)seperator;

@end
```

**NSString+Whitespace.m**

#

```
import "NSString+Whitespace.h"

@implementation NSString (Whitespace)
- (NSString *)stringByCompressingWhitespaceTo:(NSString *)seperator
{
    //NSArray *comps = [self componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
    NSArray *comps = [self componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

    NSMutableArray *nonemptyComps = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    // only copy non-empty entries
    for (NSString *oneComp in comps)
    {
        if (![oneComp isEqualToString:@""])
        {
            [nonemptyComps addObject:oneComp];
        }

    }

    return [nonemptyComps componentsJoinedByString:seperator];  // already marked as autoreleased
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you always know your string will begin with 'hello my name is ', then that is 17 characters, including the final space, so if you

```
NSString * hello = "hello my name is Donald Trump";
NSString * finalNameOnly = [hello substringFromIndex:17];
```